# Swift Class Deallocation Not Happening

Tags: swift, class, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am writing a SwiftUI based Mac OS app that show a list of added files and allows the user to select them, and remove one or more selected files from the list, or remove everything from the list.

To accomplish this I have a class, a view, and a view model.

The class is:

```
class FileItem: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var fileName: String

    init(
        fileName: String
    ) {
        self.fileName = fileName
        print("Class Initialized")
    }

    deinit {
        print("Class DeInitialized")
    }

    static func == (lhs: FileItem, rhs: FileItem) -> Bool {
        return lhs.fileName == rhs.fileName
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(fileName)
    }
}
```

The view model is:

```
extension TestView {
    @MainActor
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var myFiles: [FileItem?] = []
        @Published var fileSelection: Set<FileItem> = []

        func fileRemove() {
            for entry in self.fileSelection {
                if let idx = self.myFiles.firstIndex(where: { $0 == entry }) {
                    self.fileEntries.remove(at: idx)
                }
                self.fileSelection = []
            }
        }
    
        func fileRemoveAll() {
            self.myFiles = []
            self.fileSelection = []
        }
    }
}
```

The view is:

```
struct TestView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel

    var body: some View {

        VStack {
            Button {
                viewModel.fileRemove()
            } label: {
                Text("Remove Selected")
            }

            Button {
                viewModel.fileRemoveAll()
            } label: {
                Text("Remove All")
            }

            List(selection: $viewModel.fileSelection) {
                ForEach(viewModel.myFiles.compactMap { $0 }, id: \.self) { file in
                    Text(file.fileName)
                }
                .onMove { indices, destination in
                    viewModel.myFiles.move(
                        fromOffsets: indices,
                        toOffset: destination
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I use fileRemove, nothing gets deallocated ever. It is not until myFiles is completely empty that everything gets deallocated at once.

The other issue is that even when myFiles is [], nothing gets deallocated until the app goes into the background (i.e. I click on XCode and then it deallocates everything).

Obviously this is a stripped down example of the issue, but it's very important that when files are removed from the list (or the list is cleared out) deallocation takes place immediately in order to properly free up memory.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is a misconception about memory management. TestView is a struct; it doesn't undergo memory management in the sense that you are probably thinking of it. Thus there is nothing to trigger cleanup of memory until TestView is replaced with another TestView, and you have no control over when that is (it has to do with the needs of drawing the view). Meanwhile, ViewModel is a `@StateObject` so its job is to *persist* (that is what it means to be state object), so it isn't going to be deallocated either. Thus there is no particular reason why its FileItem properties should be deallocated on demand.

> it's very important that when files are removed from the list (or the list is cleared out) deallocation takes place immediately in order to properly free up memory

Really? These FileItems are tiny objects; how much memory could we *possibly* be talking about? It cannot be at all significant. If in real life a FileItem has as a property some class instance that is large, then you should have shown us that. In that case, instead of just setting the list of file items to an empty list or whatever, first set *that property* to `nil` or some other "empty" alternative.

Comment: I think you missed the entire issue. I am not talking about deallocating the view model. Of course that would persist. I am talking about deallocating the FileItem class instance when a file is removed. They deallocate when myFiles is empty (i.e. []) but do not when I remove only a single item for myFiles. Also, I stated this is an example. I do not need to show the entire application to get this question answered.

Comment: My answer is _about_ the FileItems.

Comment: The actual answer is that if you create an @State variable in the view as a UUID and then add .id(varName) to the List, then create an onChange(of: myFiles) { _ in varName = UUID() } the class properly deallocates. The only issue left is that it does not deallocate until the user performs any other action in the view. I'm working on correcting that now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer for anyone else needing a solution to this issue.

In your view, create an @State variable as follows:

```
@State private var refreshID = UUID()
```

Then, put two modifiers at the end of your list to id the list and monitor the onChange of your array like this:

```
List {
    // All the list code
}
.id(refreshID)
.onChange(of: myArray) { _ in
    refreshID = UUID()
}
```

Unfortunately the view will not automatically update until such time as the next interaction by the user, but that's not a big deal because if the user is no longer interacting with the app, we don't need to worry about deallocation. As soon as they interact with any other element in the app, deallocation will occur.

Hope this helps!